# How can the array be expanded with all numbers between the given numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

if two numbers are given,how could we make a sorted array with all number between them. I have a vague idea,but not being able to code it

This is how I think

- if given 1 and 50
- take Math.min,increment by 1,until <= Math.max
- push the values to a new array

How could we do this with javascript arrays? Thanks

Comment: At the very least please show us what you tried. Please note that this site is not a write-my-code-for-me service, and also not a do-my-homework-for-me service. Please see [ask].

Comment: Try something out and post your code please when you have issues with it. Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: why am i getting all the hatered for trying to help?

Comment: I'm not sure, I did not downvote, but it could be (a) because your answer has only code and no explanation, or (b) because people don't want to stimulate answering questions that show little effort from the asker.

Comment: tried fixing it, my bad didn't analyze the problem carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple `for` loop will do the trick. This will help you understand.**

```js
function retArray(a, b) {
  
  if(a > b) {
    var c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }

  let arr = [];

  for(let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  
  return arr;
}

/* Alternate Way */

function retArrayAlt(a, b) {
  let arr = [];

  for(let i = Math.min(a,b); i <= Math.max(a,b); i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(retArrayAlt(1, 10));
console.log(retArrayAlt(10, 1));
```

Comment: Why are you using `count` and not `push(i)`?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore changed the code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: also, as the question mentioned. `math.max(a,b)` and `math.min(a,b)` is much cleaner than using the intermediary variable `c`

Comment: @ChristopherMoore yes you are right, but then you have to call two extra functions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling an extra function if it improves the readability for other devs

Comment: @ChristopherMoore as you suggested i've put this too .

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to sort the array in ascending order.

There is inbuilt method to do that:

```
var maxValue = 50, minValue = 1;
var yourArray = []; // You can have your numbers array in this one.
var sortedArray = yourArray.sort(); // this will sort the array 

var resultArray =  myarray.filter(function(value){
  return (value > minValue && value < maxValue);
});
```

So resultArray is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3,9,4,33,333,12,33];
var aVal = 1;
var bVal = 50;
var dummyArray;
function sort() {
    dummyArray = array.filter(function(number,index,arr){
        return number > aVal && number < bVal && index == arr.indexOf(number);
    })
    console.log(dummyArray.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a-b;
    }))
}
sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids having to use a for loop:

```
function createArray(a, b) {
  // create array of numbers up to and including b
  const arr = [...Array(b + 1).keys()];
  // filter array to only include numbers greater than or equal to a
  return arr.filter(x => x >= a);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function generateArray(a, b) {
    var startPointer = Math.min(a, b);
    var endPointer = Math.max(a, b);

    var arr = [];

    for (var i = startPointer; i <= endPointer; i++) {
     arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

First, i tried finding the minimum number of the two, then, the maximum and generate an array from them.

Comment: can someone plese tell me what have i dont wrong here

Comment: It is not dynamic.

Comment: The question asked for numbers between 1 and 50. Your code will give numbers between 0 and 49. Your answer also doesn't accept a different range and doesn't provide any explanation for what you are doing.

Comment: tried fixing it and my bad, was not able to understand properly.